# Allow javascript in php form and avoid hacking like JsFiddle

Tags: php, javascript, jsfiddle

I have a membership website where users can embed their own code into their profile.  I would like to allow them to include embed codes on their profile such as YouTube and Javascript embed codes.

I noticed JsFiddle.net can do this. Does anybody know how to duplicate this security?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What security does jsfiddle provide? Secutiy against what?

Answer (score 5):

Set up a completely separate domain name (e.g. "exampleusercontent.com") **exclusively** for user-submitted HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Do not allow this content to be loaded through your main domain name. Then embed the user content in your pages using iframes.

If you need tighter integration than simple framing, [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) may help, allowing scripts in different frames to communicate with each other in a controlled manner.

Alternatively, [Google Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) is an open-source compiler for sandboxing third-party JavaScript, although from time to time, someone has discovered a vulnerability in it.

You may not want to rely on Caja as your sole layer of defense. After all, Facebook did give up on a similar system (called FBML/FBJS) in favor of the iframe sandboxing approach.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want security from malicious code injection, sql injection, etc.

When the form is submitted you'll need to verify the input server side. As long as you validate it there for what you expect it to be you should be okay. The only validation you do within JavaScript (if any) should be for helping the user add their information to the form and see where they've gone wrong, assistance in other words.

I've used the YouTube API in the past to validate video entries. Not sure if Vimeo has an API, I'd be surprised if it didn't though.

Comment: Validate how? To prevent what?

Comment: Vague answer to an equally vague question. Am i the only one who is not getting the question or the answer? Please explain a little.

Comment: "I assume you want security from malicious code injection" jsfiddle **is** code injection.

Comment: @PeeHaa why don't you do something constructive rather than criticising me for trying to help someone?

Comment: Because your answer doesn't make any sense perhaps? (I know neither does the question in its current form, but still it...)

Comment: I can only base my answer off the question, so I don't see what benefit there is to you flaming me.

Comment: I'm not flaming anyone. I just think this answer doesn't make much sense. That's all. Nothing personal.