# Does javascript "fake privacy" pose a security risk?

Tags: javascript, security

Javascript doesn't let you give private data or methods to objects, like you can in C++. Oh, well actually, yes it does, via some workarounds involving closure. But coming from a Python background, I am inclined to believe that "pretend privacy" (via naming conventions and documentation) is good enough, or maybe even preferable to "enforced privacy" (enforced by Javascript itself). Sure, I can think of situations where this is not true -- e.g. people interface with my code without RTFM but I get blamed -- but I'm not in that situation.

*But*, something gives me pause. Javascript guru Douglas Crockford, in "Javascript: The Good Parts" and elsewhere, repeatedly refers to fake-privacy as a "security" issue. [For example](http://websphere.sys-con.com/node/579770), "an attacker can easily access the fields directly and replace the methods with his own".

I'm confused by this. It seems to me that if I follow minimal security practices (validate, don't blindly trust, data sent from a browser to my server; don't include third-party scripts on my site without inspecting them) then there is no situation where pretend-privacy is less "secure" than enforced privacy. Is that right? If not, what's a situation where pretend-privacy versus enforced-privacy has security implications?

Comment: "Inspecting" 3rd-party scripts can be a serious challenge for some kinds of sites. If you're pulling the scripts from other servers they may change at any time.

Comment: It seems to me that if I include an evil 3rd-party script on my site, using enforced-privacy coding methods does almost nothing to mitigate the chaos that the script can cause. For example, the script can rewrite any or all HTML on the page, it can send the user's password to an evil server instead of my server, etc. etc.

Comment: Yes I agree; it's not so much about "evil" as it is "bad" I think. It's generally safe to assume that advertisers are not hostile, but they may well be incompetent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer is "No, fake privacy is fine". Here are some elaborations:

- In javascript as it exists today, you cannot include an unknown and untrusted third-party script on your webpage. It can wreak havoc: It can rewrite all the HTML on the page, it can prompt the user for his password and then send it to an evil server, etc. etc. Javascript coding style makes no difference to this basic fact. See [PleaseStand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14304760/1272672) for a discussion of methods to deal with this.
- An incompetent but not evil script might unintentionally mess things up through name conflicts. This is a good argument against creating lots of global variables with common names, but has nothing to do with whether to avoid fake-private variables. For example, my banana-selling website might use the fake-private variable `window.BANANA_STORE_MODULE.cart.__cart_item_array`. It is not completely impossible that this variable would be accidentally overwritten by a third-party script, but it's extraordinarily unlikely.
- There are [ideas floating around](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/securing-javascript/) for a *future modification* of javascript that would provide a controlled environment where untrusted code can act in prescribed ways. I could let the untrusted third-party javascript interact with my javascript through specific exposed methods, and block the third-party script from accessing the HTML, etc. If this ever exists, it could be a scenario where private variables are essential for security. But it doesn't exist yet.
- Writing clear and bug-free code is always, obviously, helpful for security. Insofar as truly-private variables and methods make it easier or harder to write clear and bug-free code, there's a security implication. Whether they are helpful or not will always be a matter of debate and taste, and whether your background is, say, C++ (where private variables are central) versus Python (where private variables are nonexistent). There are arguments in both directions, including the famous blog post [Javascript Private Variables are Evil](http://clubajax.org/javascript-private-variables-are-evil/).

For my part, I will keep using fake privacy: A leading underscore (or whatever) indicates to myself and my collaborators that some property or method is not part of the publicly-supported interface of a module. My fake-privacy code is more readable (IMO), and I have more freedom in structuring it (e.g. a closure cannot span two files), and I can access those fake-private variables while I debug and experiment. I'm not going to worry that these programs are somehow more insecure than any other javascript program.

Answer (score 1):

Not in itself. However, it does mean you cannot safely load untrusted JavaScript code into your HTML documents, as Crockford points out. If you really need to run such untrusted JavaScript code in the browser (*e.g.* for user-submitted widgets in social networking sites), consider iframe sandboxing.

As a Web developer, your security problem is often that major Internet advertising brokers do not support (or even [prohibit](https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48182#beh)) framing their ad code. Unfortunately, you have to trust Google to not deliver malicious JavaScript, whether intentionally or unintentionally (*e.g.* they get hacked).

Here is a short description of iframe sandboxing I had posted as an answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162492/allow-javascript-in-php-form-and-avoid-hacking-like-jsfiddle):

> Set up a completely separate domain name (e.g. "exampleusercontent.com") **exclusively** for user-submitted HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Do not allow this content to be loaded through your main domain name. Then embed the user content in your pages using iframes.
>
> If you need tighter integration than simple framing, [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) may help, allowing scripts in different frames to communicate with each other in a controlled manner.

Comment: The statement "you cannot safely load untrusted JavaScript code into your HTML documents" -- it seems to me that this has nothing to do with fake-privacy javascript coding. It's true regardless of how I write my javascript code. Right? After all, the untrusted script can directly rewrite any or all of the HTML, etc. etc.

Comment: @SteveB: Yes. As far as I know, no web browser has native functionality (other than the iframe) for restricting scripts to certain parts of the page, although such functionality certainly could be implemented. The "fake privacy" really only matters once that is addressed.